# Need to swap a string with another string in a file via bash script

Tags: bash, apache, shell, awk

I need to replace a keyword with another keyword/string in a Linux file. i.e

```
IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml 
index.htm
</IfModule>
```

Here I want to replace or swap index.html to index.php in 2nd line or I want to prioritize index.php in place of index.html and put index.html inplace of index.php.

I have to do the above mentioned task via a shell script and for that I have already tried the command:

```
awk 'NR==2 { t = $2; $2 = $5; $5 = t; print; } ' abc.txt
```

But it is not saving in the file i.e abc.txt in which I want to change the content.

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For any command `cmd`, to update the original file:

```
cmd file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

If you're using GNU awk you could instead use `awk -i inplace '...' file` and it'll do the above for you internally, just like `sed -i` and `perl -i`, etc. do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with just `sed`:

```
 sed -i.bak 's/index.html/index.php/g' abc.txt
```

That will replace ALL ocurrences of `index.html` with `index.php` in `abc.txt` and will save a copy of `abc.txt` original contents on `abc.txt.bak`.

Comment: Well, what it is doing is, it is replacing just inex.html as index.php and the later index.php is still there. So there is 2 index.php there

Answer (score 0):

another option is with the below perl command :

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/index.html/index.php/g;' abc.txt
```

Comment: I want to swap the index.html with index.php, please see my question, I want index.php to show inplace of index.html and index.html in place of index.php.